# Clarification of Definition: Free Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, lie-algebras

I need some clarification on the definition of free algebra. Here is an extract from Lie Algebras and Lie Groups by Jean-Pierre Serre:

[image]
[image]

I am somewhat confused about the definition of free algebra. Let say $X=\{x\}$ and $k=\mathbb{R}$, then the free algebra $A_X$ consists of all elements of the form $$rx,rxx, r((xx)x), r(x(xx)), r(((xx)x)x), r((x(xx))x), \cdots (r\in\mathbb{R}),$$ right? Am I right in saying that in $A_X$, $(xx)x$ and $x(xx)$ are different elements?

Comment: Yes, they are. But keep in mind that Serre's notion of "algebra" is what most of us would call a "magmatic algebra" or "nonassociative nonunital algebra" (the negative adjectives merely mean that associativity and unitality are not required; they might nevertheless be satisfied). So the free algebra in this sense is not the usual notion of a free algebra (isomorphic to a tensor algebra).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @darijgrinberg!! It is now very clear to me.